# Calculating in a row appearances of each character

Tags: c, algorithm

I've created a program that is calculating how many each character appear in a string. I want it to calculate consecutive appearances (in a row) of the same character and then to print the character with greatest number of consecutive appearances (greatest number of one type character in a row). I do not know how to do that, but I would like to do that with smallest amount of modifications possible (I guess it is solvable with use of loops, I was thinking about comparing one character with another but I do not know how to write a proper code)

My code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "ctype.h"

int count_nonspace(const char* str)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        if (!isspace(*str++))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[127];
    int i = 0, j = 0, count[127] = { 0 };

    char string[100] = "Hello world";
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        for (j = 33; j<127; j++)
        {
            if (string[i] == (j))
            {
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j< 127; j++)
    {
        if (count[j] > 0)
        if (j < ' ' + 1) 
            printf("\n%d -> %d", count[j], j);
        else
            printf("\n%d -> %c", count[j], char(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a clue as to what you want.  What is the problem with your existing code?  looks like you are attempting to count #occurrences of each character.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I've retained your formatting in the final for loop, but note that both print conditionals are within `if (count[j] > 0)`